# push notifications: working on 1st test iPhone, but not on others

Tags: ios, push-notification

I successfully registered all certificates etc. for push notifications. I installed my App via USB to first iPhone (iOS 6 if that matters). `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is called on that iPhone and I'm able to receive push notifications.

But then I installed my App to other 2 devices (also via USB, but iOS 7 this time) and `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`is never fired on those two. What am I missing? I was setting up first iPhone long time ago so probably I forgot to do some required step, I don't know.

So again to sum it up: now all 3 devices have the same latest version of application, but `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is being fired only on first device. Others 2 never ask a permission for push notifications at start up.

Answer (score 0):

I found it - I was required to go to Apple's Member Center, and update my "Provisioning Profile". There were 2 other devices visible but they were unchecked in provisioning profile and therefore not allowed to receive Push Notifications. So I checked 2 other devices, downloaded and re-installed new profile, now everything is fine.